# Wagtail site is failing to load media files using DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: django, digital-ocean, wagtail

I am building a Wagtail site, using DigitalOcean Spaces. The static files are loading OK, but when I try to upload an image from the admin, it can't upload the image into the media folder at Spaces, showing error. This is my config for the storage:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('SPACES_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'BUCKET_NAME'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_app/static'),
]

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'spaces-folder/static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'spaces-folder/media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

I am also using a custom_storages.py file with the two following classes to use static and media files in the same Spaces bucket, following [this tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/):

```
# custom_storages.py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Just says: Server error Report this error to your webmaster with the following information: - 0

Comment: I also tried to create the media folder in the exact location at Spaces, but Django creates the folder automatically, it seems like if I can't load the file, but the app has access to the storage. I tried to modify also the CORS permits, and everything is checked (GET, PUT, DELETE, etc.)

Comment: At the browser console I get the following error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Also, the same configuration works in my machine locally, I just added the STATIC and MEDIA_URL variables so Django could run